# How do I add panel class into Frame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I wanted to create a panel class and insert on MyFrame class. I have several panel class to be insert in. The issue now is that the frame class does not show the panel.

This is my Frame class.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    private JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel jLabel2 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel jLabel3 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel jLabel4 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel jLabel5 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel jLabel6 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel jLabel7 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel jLabel8 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel jLabel9 = new JLabel();
    private JTextField FirstName = new JTextField();
    private JTextField Surname = new JTextField();
    private JTextField SurnameAMarriage = new JTextField();
    private JTextField Gender = new JTextField();
    private JTextField StreetNumber = new JTextField();
    private JTextField StreetName = new JTextField();
    private JTextField Suburb = new JTextField();
    private JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
    private JTextArea Remark = new JTextArea();
    private JRadioButton GMale = new JRadioButton();
    private JRadioButton GFemale = new JRadioButton();
    private JButton BtAddSpouse = new JButton();
    private JButton BtAddMother = new JButton();
    private JButton BtAddFather = new JButton();
    private JButton BtAddChildren = new JButton();
    private JButton BtNewFamily = new JButton();
    private JButton BtEditingMode = new JButton();
    private JButton BtViewingMode = new JButton();
    private JButton BtSubmit = new JButton();
    private JButton BtReset = new JButton();
    private JButton BtBack = new JButton();
    ArrayList <Person> Family = new ArrayList<Person>();
    int i = 0;
    AddNew Addnew = new AddNew();



    public MyFrame(){

    CardLayout C1 = new CardLayout();
    ViewingMode VM = new ViewingMode();

    JPanel panelCont = new JPanel();
    panelCont.setLayout(C1);
    add(VM);
    C1.show(panelCont, "1");
    JFrame Frame = new JFrame();

    Frame.add(panelCont);
    Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    Frame.pack();
    Frame.setVisible(true);      

}
```

This would be my Viewing class.

```
 public class ViewingMode extends JPanel{


    private class ActionNewFamily implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            Family.clear();
           Addnew.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    private class ActionViewingMode implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){


        }
    }
    private class ActionAddFather implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        }
    }public ViewingMode(){

    JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();
    JLabel jLabel2 = new JLabel();
    JLabel jLabel3 = new JLabel();
    JLabel jLabel4 = new JLabel();
    JLabel jLabel5 = new JLabel();
    JLabel jLabel6 = new JLabel();
    JLabel jLabel7 = new JLabel();
    JLabel jLabel8 = new JLabel();
    JLabel jLabel9 = new JLabel();
    JTextField FirstName = new JTextField();
    JTextField Surname = new JTextField();
    JTextField SurnameAMarriage = new JTextField();
    JTextField Gender = new JTextField();
    JTextField StreetNumber = new JTextField();
    JTextField StreetName = new JTextField();
    JTextField Suburb = new JTextField();
    JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
    JTextArea Remark = new JTextArea();
    JRadioButton GMale = new JRadioButton();
    JRadioButton GFemale = new JRadioButton();
    JButton BtAddSpouse = new JButton();
    JButton BtAddMother = new JButton();
    JButton BtAddFather = new JButton();
    JButton BtAddChildren = new JButton();
    JButton BtNewFamily = new JButton();
    JButton BtEditingMode = new JButton();
    JButton BtViewingMode = new JButton();
    JButton BtSubmit = new JButton();
    JButton BtReset = new JButton();
    JButton BtViewFamily = new JButton();
    JButton BtBack = new JButton();
    JScrollPane jScrollPane2 = new JScrollPane();
    JList<String> jList1 = new JList<>();

    jLabel1.setText("First Name");
    jLabel2.setText("Surname");
    jLabel3.setText("Surname after marriage");
    jLabel4.setText("Gender");
    jLabel5.setText("Street Number");
    jLabel6.setText("Remark");

    SurnameAMarriage.setToolTipText("");

    Remark.setColumns(20);
    Remark.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(Remark);


    FirstName.setEditable(false);
    Surname.setEditable(false);
    SurnameAMarriage.setEditable(false);
    StreetNumber.setEditable(false);
    Remark.setEditable(false);
    StreetName.setEditable(false);
    Suburb.setEditable(false);
    Gender.setEditable(false);

    jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
    jLabel7.setText("Viewing mode");

    BtViewFamily.setText("View Family");

    BtEditingMode.setText("Editing Mode");
    BtEditingMode.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        EditingMode EDM = new EditingMode();
        EDM.setVisible(true);

     }
    });
    jLabel8.setText("Street Name");
    jLabel9.setText("Suburb");

    jList1.setModel(new AbstractListModel<String>() {
        String[] strings = { "" };
        public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
        public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
    });
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jList1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGap(59, 59, 59)
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addComponent(jLabel6)
                        .addGap(129, 129, 129)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 265, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel8)
                            .addComponent(jLabel9))
                        .addGap(101, 101, 101)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(StreetName, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 265, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(Suburb, GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 265, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5))
                    .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(FirstName, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 265, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(Surname)
                        .addComponent(SurnameAMarriage)
                        .addComponent(Gender)
                        .addComponent(StreetNumber)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                            .addComponent(jLabel7)))))
            .addGap(83, 83, 83)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 171, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(91, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(253, 253, 253)
            .addComponent(BtEditingMode)
            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(BtViewFamily)
            .addGap(123, 123, 123))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel7)
            .addGap(20, 20, 20)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addComponent(FirstName, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(Surname, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addComponent(SurnameAMarriage, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addComponent(Gender, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                        .addComponent(StreetNumber, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel8)
                        .addComponent(StreetName, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel9)
                        .addComponent(Suburb, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 289, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(31, 31, 31)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(BtViewFamily)
                .addComponent(BtEditingMode))
            .addContainerGap(139, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are adding components to two frames:  your MyFrame instance and `Frame`.  I suggest you remove `extends JFrame` from your MyFrame class.  Extending window classes is never a good idea; this confusion is one reason why.

Comment: How about if I would like to add actionListener, do I add in the frame or in the panel class?

Comment: Add an ActionListener to a particular JButton in the same class which creates that JButton.

Comment: 1) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).